# Use participle or "which" to start a nonessential clause?

Tags: grammar

Is there anything wrong with this sentence:

The city pays landlords more than someone with a rental voucher can pay, **which only exacerbates** NY's already severe housing shortage.

Is this sentence better? if so why?
The city pays landlords more than someone with a rental voucher can pay, **only exacerbating** NY's already severe housing shortage.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you think it's better? And, if so, why?

Comment: As these examples from [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/which) illustrate, 'which' in these constructions can refer either to the immediately preceding (or logically sensible) noun phrase _or_ the preceding main clause: That bar on Milton Street, which by the way is very nice, is owned by Trevor's brother. / 
She says it's Charlotte's fault, which is stupid.... / He showed me round the town, which was very kind of him. The second variant is also fine, using a non-finite clause to add the desired additional information.

Answer (score -2):

I think the biggest problem is the unnecessary use of hyperbole. How can you be sure that the city's offerings *only* have a negative impact, and not also a small positive impact?

> The city pays landlords more than someone with a rental voucher can pay, which exacerbates New York's already severe housing shortage.

...is what I would write (note that I also did not abbreviate New York). Using "which" makes the sentence clearer and helps to separate the two ideas. It gives the reader an opportunity to consider how the two ideas relate to each other, and to make up their own opinion about the causality of the situation.

Comment: You've got the wrong sense of _only_ here. The one in play is: _4.
a. In the last analysis or final outcome; inevitably: 'actions that will only make things worse'._  [ [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/only)]